# Python - text mining - TypeError: __hash__ method should return an integer

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-mining

I am working on a classification problem in python. Fact is, I'm not good yet in python. So I have the same problem since a long time now and I don't know how to fix it. I hope you could help me :)

This is my code :

```
tableau = pandas.DataFrame({'Exigence':exigence,'Résumé':resume})    

df2, targets = encode_target(tableau,"Exigence")
features = list(df2.columns[:4])

for line in resume:
   terms = prep.ngram_tokenizer(text=line)
   mx.add_doc(doc_id='some-unique-identifier',
              doc_class=df2["Target"],
              doc_terms=terms,
              frequency=True,
              do_padding=True)
```

And I have this error :

```
objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-072e9c71917a>", line 7, in <module>
    do_padding=True)

  File "C:\Users\nouguierc\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-  packages\irlib\matrix.py", line 222, in add_doc
    if doc_class in self.classes:

TypeError: __hash__ method should return an integer
```

When I go the the line 222 of matrix.py I see this :

```
    if doc_class in self.classes:
        self.classes[doc_class].add(my_doc_terms)
```

The function containing those lines is :

```
def add_doc(self, doc_id = '', doc_class='', doc_terms=[], 
            frequency=False, do_padding=False):
    ''' Add new document to our matrix:
        doc_id: Identifier for the document, eg. file name, url, etc. 
        doc_class: You might need this in classification.
        doc_terms: List of terms you got after tokenizing the document.
        frequency: If true, term occurences is incremented by one.
                    Else, occurences is only 0 or 1 (a la Bernoulli)
        do_padding: Boolean. Check do_padding() for more info.
    ''' 
    # Update list of terms if new term seen.
    # And document (row) with its associated data.
    my_doc_terms = SuperList()
    for term in doc_terms:
        term_idx = self.terms.unique_append(term)
        #my_doc_terms.insert_after_padding(self.terms.index(term))
        if frequency:
            my_doc_terms.increment_after_padding(term_idx,1)
        else:
            my_doc_terms.insert_after_padding(term_idx,1)
    self.docs.append({  'id': doc_id, 
                        'class': doc_class, 
                        'terms': my_doc_terms})
    # Update list of document classes if new class seen.
    # self.classes.unique_append(doc_class)
    if doc_class in self.classes:
        self.classes[doc_class].add(my_doc_terms)
    else:
        self.classes[doc_class] = my_doc_terms
    if do_padding: 
        self.do_padding()
```

What do you think about my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an **object** as `doc_class`, check what `df2['Target']` returns, probably a pandas Series, convert it to a single string, and pass it then.

Comment: df2["Target"] is : pandas.core.series.Series. This is lines with numbers (1; 3; 2; 6; 6; 2;...). I should just keep a string : 1 3 2 6 6 2 ???

Comment: this means you are using whole method wrong. This is supposed to get **single document**, with **a single label**